# Laravel helper functions do not load

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I created a new Laravel 7 project and none of the framework helper functions after available.

For instance, if I run `studly_case('blah')` in Tinker I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function studly_case() in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

I've done the usual:

```
composer install
composer dumpautoload
```

However, no luck.

Do helper functions need some special composer include in v7 that isn't done by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include deprecated helper functions you have to use the project [helpers](https://github.com/laravel/helpers).

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

Laravel has been moving away from helpers and want people to use the static implementations. An Alternative is to call it on the Str implementation.

```
Str::studly('studly');
```